# Visual Studio Code Remote - Is file indexing done on the remote server or on my local machine? Can I make the indexing faster?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual studio code currently to navigate source code that I have on a RHEL machine. Searching for code usages is slow (atleast way slower than having code checked out locally- which is expected). The project I have is pretty big (Mysql open source code). My questions are:

When I search for usages - does it do the search on the remote machine or does it pull files locally and do the search? Is it possible to make the searches faster? I do ignore folders that I don't care about already.

Answer (score 0):

I would say judging from this in v1.65 that the remote files are downloaded and indexed locally.  Perhaps with the new process of downloading the entire **repository** and indexing it all you will get better performance.  That specifically applies to repositories so you will have to see if it makes any difference for files on your RHEL machine.

> Workspace search and find all references will now download and index a
> full copy of the repository by default, rather than defaulting to
> providing partial results as before. There are several settings to
> configure this:
>
> - `remoteHub.indexing.verboseDownloadNotification`: controls whether the  download notification is shown as a popup (default) or in the
>   status bar
> - `remoteHub.indexing.maxIndexSize`: controls the size limit of indexes to download - if this is exceeded the download will be
>   cancelled and partial results will be provided. Leave this empty to
>   never download repositories and use partial results always.

- from [v1.65 Release Notes: Remote Repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md#remote-repositories)